# How to put current date in PrimeFaces inputMask?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a input in which I want current date to be displayed.
It looks like this:

```
<p:inputMask id="kalendarz" autocomplete="false" styleClass="#{cc.attrs.styleClass}" mask="99.99.9999"
                     value="#{cc.attrs.value}" required="#{cc.attrs.required and param['fillDataAction']==null}" disabled="#{cc.attrs.isDisabled}"
                     style="#{cc.attrs.style}" onchange="#{cc.attrs.onchange}" readonly="#{cc.attrs.readonly}" label="#{cc.attrs.label}"
                     onblur="#{cc.attrs.onblur}" onselect="#{cc.attrs.onselect}">
    <f:converter converterId="#{cc.attrs.converter}">
</p:inputMask>
```

How can I display current date in this inputMask? I was trying using javascript to setAttribute placeHolder, but it doesn't work

Comment: You can set current time as default value for cc.attrs.value in your controller.

Answer (score -1):

try

```
@Named("cc")
@Viewscoped
public class YourBean implements Serializable{
     ....

     @PostConstruct
     public void init(){
           ...
           this.attrs.setValue(new Date());//this should 
           ...
     }
     ...
}
```